# Why is "on" used instead of "in" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Prepositions are still very difficult for me.

Why is "on" used instead of "in" in this sentence?

> This library has the definitive collection of books on ancient Egypt.

I have no idea. Why is that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Advice: some are logical, others need to be memorized. Books on [a subject] should be memorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 'on' is basically short for 'on the subject of ...'

> a collection of books **on** ancient Egypt = a collection of books on the subject of ancient Egypt
>
> a collection of books **in** ancient Egypt = a collection of books which is physically located in Egypt

Comment: Also *books **on** ancient Latin* = *books **on the subject of** ancient Latin*, whereas *books **in** ancient Latin* = *books **written in the language of** ancient Latin*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers also a good point.

Comment: There are other possible meanings for ***in*** in such contexts *(books in the Industrial Revolution* = *books written / being circulated **at that time**)* - but apart from the absolutely literal ***books on my bookshelf***, I can't offhand think of any other possible meanings for ***on*** here.

Comment: "'books in the Industrial Revolution" sounds a bit awkward to me. I would prefer "books of the Industrial Revolution" to mean books written during that period.

Comment: Well, [*Books **in** Medieval England*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22books+in+medieval+england%22) gets an estimated 3500 hits in Google Books, and seems completely unambiguous and natural to me. But [*Books **of** Medieval England*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22books+of+medieval+england%22) gets just 5 hits, and there are thousands of hits for [*Books **of** mathematics*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Books+of+mathematics%22), which to me suggests that ***of*** occurs quite often with the sense ***on the subject of*** in this context.

Comment: Yes, books in [an epoch]. So, book in the Industrial Revolution means at the time of it.

Comment: The number of Google Books hits you cited is rather misleading. The full string of the very first result is "the price of books in Medieval England" which is hardly the same meaning as 'books produced in the time of Medieval England. The second hit is "Insular French books in Medieval England" which is also not the same meaning as you quoted. But this is off-topic anyway.